# ROR - Trying to create objects using nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create objects using nested forms in my bookings/new view. I've got a Flight model, a Booking model and a Passenger model.
The Flight model `has_many :passengers` and `has_many :bookings`
The Booking model `belongs_to :flight` and `has_many :passengers`
The Passenger model ``belongs_to :booking`and`belongs_to :flight`

Here is my view bookings/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Create new booking</h1>

For flight <%= @flight.id %>: <%= @flight.departure_airport.code %> - <%= @flight.arrival_airport.code %>
on: <%= @flight.departure_date %><br><br>

<%= form_with model: @booking, local: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>

    <%= f.fields_for :passengers do |passenger| %>
      <%= passenger.hidden_field :flight_id, value: @flight.id %>
      <%= passenger.label :name %><br>
      <%= passenger.text_field :name %><br>
      <%= passenger.label :email %><br>
      <%= passenger.email_field :email %><br><br>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Bookings Controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:flight_id])
    @num_of_pass = params[:num_of_pass].to_i
    @booking = Booking.new
    @num_of_pass.times do
      @booking.passengers.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:booking][:flight_id])
    @booking = @flight.bookings.build(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      puts "SAVED"
    else
      puts @booking.errors.full_messages
      puts "NOT SAVED"
    end

  end

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:flight_id, passengers_attributes:[:name, :email, :flight_id])
    end 
end
```

The error I get is that "the passengers booking can't be blank"
If I build the booking, then save it, then build the passengers, it works fine, but I'm trying to use the strong parameters that are nested.

The problem seems to be that the booking model isn't being saved prior to creating the passengers.

I've been banging my head against this for hours and hoping someone can give me some insight

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had validations in my Passenger model. It wouldn't build because I had `validates :booking_id, presence: true`

Does anyone know how to keep the validations, but also allow it to build?